# Can someone explain how 8%20 is equal to 8 and not 0

Tags: operators

Can someone explain how 8%20 is equal to 8 and not 0
I thought the answer would be zero but it's eight, but how?

Comment: `8%20` is the remainder after you divide `8` by `20`. How many times does `20` go into `8`? Zero. What is left over (the remainder)? `8`.

Comment: % is not the division operator. It is reminder operator.

Comment: aka [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation)

Comment: almost all languages, it's fairly standard.

Comment: thank you for explaining now it is clear to me, I was missing the whole point of the remainder part

Answer (score 0):

a%b equals the remainder of (a/b).

Because 8 = 0*20 + 8, the remainder in (8/20) is 8.
So 8%20 == 8.

Answer (score 0):

% is the operator for modulos, which returns the remainder of the division of 8 / 20.

Answer (score 0):

It works only for integer data types in programming languages such as C, C++, C#, and Java.
If you do 8/20, the answer is the quotient 0, but your calculated floating point number is 0.4.  If you perform 8%20, then the answer is the remainder 8.

```
int x=8 ,r;
r=a%20;
printf("Output = %d",r);
Output = 8
```